# Windows 10 Error Code 31 "The request is not supported" in Device Manager for WLAN NIC

Tags: windows-10, wireless-networking, device-manager

I have an Hp EliteDesk 800 G3 DM 35W (mini) PC. The SSD failed.

After installing Windows 10 on a new SSD everything seems to work OK, EXCEPT the Wireless Card (Intel Dual Band AC 8265) is not recognized.

After trying everything I could find on various forums with no success I stumbled on the Install Legacy Hardware option in Device Manager.

Using it I managed to get the WLAN NIC to appear in Device Manager - but with the dreaded exclamation mark of misery, and the error Code 31 "The request is not supported".

Then I could install the latest driver from Intel (version 20.70.30.1), but still I get Code 31 "The request is not supported".

I have tried replacing the NIC and reinstalling Windows 10 again, both without success.

Installing the WLAN NIC driver package from HP (sp123564) doesn't help.

I tried turning off memory integrity (as suggested on another forum) but that had no effect.

I am now completely stumped. Any help much appreciated.

From Windows Event Log. This seems to be the relevant sequence of events (apologies for the bold font, was pasted from plain text, can't see how it got tuned on or how to turn it off):

### Driver Management has concluded the process to add Service vwifibus for Device Instance ID ROOT\NET\0000 with the following status: 0.

Device ROOT\NET\0000 was configured.

### Driver Name: oem46.inf
Class Guid: {4d36e972-e325-11ce-bfc1-08002be10318}
Driver Date: 01/13/2022
Driver Version: 20.70.30.1
Driver Provider: Intel
Driver Section: Install_MPCIEX_GENM2_8265_AC_2x2_HMC_WINT_64_AC
Driver Rank: 0xFC0000
Matching Device Id: pci\ven_8086&dev_24fd&subsys_00108086
Outranked Drivers: netwtw06.inf:pci\ven_8086&dev_24fd&subsys_00108086:00FC0000 oem43.inf:pci\ven_8086&dev_24fd&subsys_00108086:00FC0000
Device Updated: true
Parent Device: HTREE\ROOT\0

Device ROOT\NET\0000 had a problem starting.

Driver Name: oem46.inf
Class Guid: {4d36e972-e325-11ce-bfc1-08002be10318}
Service: Netwtw06
Lower Filters:
Upper Filters: vwifibus
Problem: 0x1F
Problem Status: 0xC00000BB

Answer (score 0):

The Hp EliteDesk 800 G3 DM has a BIOS setting which can hide the M.2 WLAN card from the OS.

Kudos to https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=LyVV78qhGdg who mentioned in passing to check WiFi was set on in BIOS, which gave me the crucial clue. Never knew this could be a thing!

The solution was actually in the manual on p.89 (https://www.itouchbiometrics.com/Manuals/HP_G3.pdf), but I didn't realise "Run Computer Setup and enable network controller" actually meant "enter BIOS and ensure OS is set to see M.2 Network Card."

The actual setting is: Advanced | Built-in Device Options | M.2 USB/Bluetooth.

I never changed the BIOS prior to installing Windows 10 on the new SSD, but that setting had somehow reverted to "hide".

Simply switching it to "unhide" fixed the issue. On boot the WLAN and Bluetooth drivers installed and shown in Device Manager.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).